# Solve a Cubic Equation

Tags: code-golf, math

### Input

- Your program will take in the integer coefficients of the equation \$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0\$ as inputs (a, b, c, and d).

### Output

- All real solutions of the input equation, with an accuracy of at least the thousandths place, sorted from smallest to largest.

### Rules

- Built-in equation solver are not allowed
- Native math libraries that do not solve equations may be used
- If you have any questions, please ask in comment

### Examples

1. .

   Input:

   ```
   1 2 3 4
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   -1.651
   ```
2. .

   Input:

   ```
   1 3 0 -1
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   -2.879 -0.653 0.532
   ```

Comment: Challenges must have an [objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria). I would recommend [tag:code-golf]. In future, please post your questions in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first to get feedback. Also, disallowing built-in methods tends to lead to a less fun challenge

Comment: Quartics next :)

Comment: @Anush [we already have a challenge for quartics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21438/shortest-program-to-solve-a-quartic-equation?rq=1) (but, bizarrely, not for cubics)

Comment: Also, I'd recommend against strict input/output methods like "separated by spaces", as it makes less of the challenge about solving the problem, but more boring boilerplate I/O logic

Comment: @pxeger My reputation was too low to post in the Sandbox.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest loosening the challenge by removing the rules about space-separated input/output, required rounding, and output needing to be sorted.

Comment: Does the output have to be uniqified, or can numbers repeat multiple times?

Comment: This is badly in need of a full explanation and a worked example.

Comment: Should also ditch the *built-in equation solver are not allowed* rule, why have such a rule in a code-golf challenge?