# Multiplicity of a root of a polynomial

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials

Let \$p(x)\$ be a polynomial. We say \$a\$ is a **root of multiplicity \$k\$** of \$p(x)\$, if there is another polynomial \$s(x)\$ such that \$p(x)=s(x)(x-a)^k\$ and \$s(a)\ne0\$.

For example, the polynomial \$p(x)=x^3+2x^2-7x+4=(x+4)(x-1)^2\$ has \$1\$ and \$-4\$ as roots. \$1\$ is a root of multiplicity \$2\$. \$-4\$ is a root of multiplicity \$1\$.

### Task

Given a nonzero polynomial \$p(x)\$ and a root \$a\$ of it, find the multiplicity of \$a\$.

The coefficients of \$p(x)\$ are all integers. \$a\$ is also an integer.

You may take the polynomial in any reasonable format. For example, the polynomial \$x^4-4x^3+5x^2-2x\$ may be represented as:

- a list of coefficients, in descending order: `[1,-4,5,-2,0]`;
- a list of coefficients, in ascending order:`[0,-2,5,-4,1]`;
- a string representation of the polynomial, with a chosen variable, e.g., `x`: `"x^4-4*x^3+5*x^2-2*x"`;
- a built-in polynomial object, e.g., `x^4-4*x^3+5*x^2-2*x` in PARI/GP.

When you take input as a list of coefficients, you may assume that the leading coefficient (the first one in descending order) is nonzero.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Testcases

Here I use coefficient lists in descending order:

```
[1,2,-7,4], 1 -> 2
[1,2,-7,4], -4 -> 1
[1,-4,5,-2,0], 0 -> 1
[1,-4,5,-2,0], 1 -> 2
[1,-4,5,-2,0], 2 -> 1
[4,0,-4,4,1,-2,1], -1 -> 2
[1,-12,60,-160,240,-192,64,0], 2 -> 6
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154001/find-integral-roots-of-a-polynomial).

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Ærċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9GR7v@hh5cfWqr0/3@0oY6Rjq65jkmsjgIaW9dEx1RH10jHgDDXRMcAJGCiYwgSMoSqMDTSMQOKGwIJIxMQwxIoAFQa@99QRwGoXMFARwHIMgJyQBQA)

Takes input as a list of coefficients in ascending order. The Footer on TIO reverses each of the test cases to fit this.

### How it works

```
Ærċ - Main link. Takes a polynomial P on the left, and a root r on the right
Ær  - Calculate the roots of P, with repeats
  ċ - Count the number of times r appears in the list of roots
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 62 bytes

Expects `(root)(polynomial)`, where *polynomial* is a list of coefficients in ascending order.

```javascript
(r,s=0)=>g=p=>s?-1:1+g(p.map((c,i)=>(s+=c*r**i,c*i)).slice(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHBasMwDIbveQod5VROI@N1dMPZaU8Rcgiek3qkdbBHXz@zYYPBto7pIMSvT78Eeh2vY7LRr2/yEl7cNpkNIyXTCtPNZjVdepL8wLsZ1@Y8roiWfG5h2hlbx7r2ZGsvRJMWbx2yENtjXwH00DMpkvekBwKGHyLr@z2ob7DUv8L8CUtNdyQVtVlv/wPzX2d8hdVtZ01twTVxGeByOt9yZkWHPME5KV2KYxb0x6YBCnyohqqZQnwe7Qmxh5UgwiDAdGDDJYXFNUuYccIo8j@iu7qYHIoc2zs)

#### How?

This simply recursively computes the successive derivatives of the polynomial:

$$P_{k+1}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}P_k(x)$$

until \$P_k(r)\neq 0\$ and returns the number of iterations.

#### Commented

```javascript
(                   // outer function taking:
  r,                //   the root r
  s = 0             //   the sum s of the polynomial evaluation
) =>                //
g = p =>            // inner recursive function taking the polynomial p[]
s ?                 // if s is not equal to 0:
  -1                //   stop the recursion and decrement the final result
:                   // else:
  1 +               //   increment the final result
  g(                //   do a recursive call with the derivative of p[]:
    p.map((c, i) => //     for each coefficient c at position i in p[]:
      (             //
        s +=        //       add to s:
          c *       //         the coefficient multiplied by
          r ** i,   //         the root raised to the power of i
        c * i       //       set the new coefficient to c * i
      )             //
    ).slice(1)      //     end of map(); remove the leading term
  )                 //   end of recursive call
```

---

## 59 bytes

A version without `slice()` suggested by [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh).

```javascript
(r,s=k=0)=>g=p=>s?~k:g(p.map(c=>(s+=0|c*r**i,c*i++),i=k--))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHBSsQwEIbvfYo5Ju2km4S4ojL15FOUHkpMu7XrJiSyJ/HVawIKgrrifxiGn2/@GZin8TwmG5fwIk7@0W0TbSxiopUkp26mQF26f1tvZxba5zEwSx1LDclXW8e6XtDWS9NwXGgVgvPtrq8AeugVahTXaAYEBT8o@7sd6G@wML/C6hMWBq9QaJTZl/@B1V9nfIX15WSDsuAGVRlQ5XR1KVlp3OcJlYs2pbnJhvnYNECB99VQtZOPD6M9MNZDQIgwcKAOrD8lf3Tt0c9sYpHnZ0R3djE5xrO2dw)

Comment: `(r,s=k=0)=>g=p=>s?~k:g(p.map(c=>(s+=0|c*r**i,c*i++),i=k--))`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 65 bytes

```python
f=lambda p,r,c=0:(q:=[c:=b+c*r for b in p])!=c==0and-~f(q[:-1],r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BbsMgDIbveQqPE3SmAka7DYm@SJYDSRsViRJKo0m79NVTmDa1k@aDZX3@/Mvpaz5O8eUt5WUZbXCnfu8gYcbBCkPPxraDsf3zsMowThl68BFSx57sYK1wcc@vIz23hssOM1uqEqpCCGlaiQr5K@oOQQLfgfqDuK5MVsY1bpArFAWLf@n9/pGqH1ejqFyjrBtZwx8OpMJt2cvSlK7DewH6HrBtyrfry5x9omx9ScHPlHxEwkwDpTxOYOHkEj18uoDh1@A7wti3kbKPMx3pyjOc2HID)

Divides by the linear factor X-root and recurses if the remainder is zero.

Comment: Nice method! This taught me that when evaluating a polynomial at a value `r` with Horner's method, the intermediate results are also the coefficients obtained by dividing out by `x-r`.

Comment: Amazing what you can do with `lambda` and list comprehensions. [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/79299b2a0985cf9b492e0168c5358772) is a Python gist of call graph of `f(*([1,-12,60,-160,240,-192,64,0], 2))`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.polynomials`, 58 bytes

```factor
[ [ 2dup polyval 0 = ] [ dup pdiff swap ] produce length ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHBTsQgEIbvfYrfB2CzkFqjxr0aL16Mp80eCKVusxQQqGbT7LPXgeweNE3UIZMhf@bjB6aTKrkwv748PT/e4aCD1QaDTPuVd@Zo3dBLExH1@6it0hEyRqcifNApHX3obcJ9VU0VKCZwyhrsBoK2J1oLcQW2gTgDrP6dKAA/A@uSTOA6s8vIN4D/FbhcSfzXgfFiw/IL6sysqfygFhwa6uW3AqImN96QkOvlGwrQVKdq3mIL0Y4eeSAf0hD6gB2JRWv7rkP8lJ4kH1w7Kg2j7VvaYzdPdFAZ2GaghhWU0TLMXw)

Takes `root polynomial` where the polynomial is given as a sequence of coefficients in ascending order. Uses the method described in Arnauld's [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253297/97916). `polyval` evaluates a polynomial given a value and `pdiff` computes the derivative of a polynomial. `produce` creates a list of successive derivatives until one evaluates to nonzero. Then take the length of the list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 105 bytes

```rust
|a,r|{let mut j=0;while 0==(0..).zip(&mut*a).map(|(i,c)|{let d=*c*r.pow(i);*c*=i as i32;d}).sum(){j+=1}j}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5Ra4QwEITf/RXTlyNrY4hWLNeQ/pGjlHAXaeS01igHp/52m9i@FroPy7DMfDvD5MctqTu0xnWMMCcIc7Uj6hfUHTu003hyT8UbR9iE7BWTd3cLjW0xfFjm6A0mNFqq24e7WkitmRSCxN31OyA1JFrTs4U5fqafyEWn53QQ/eeNOVJBawfj4xN1WUn4qWU0N486X5t1U8ley3hvh/Hdfj2wegfjVHJkzxwFRx4q5hQkqf@Zs5Ji4k@35KhiIj@GQFHKKKt43NUvpAiMKjDWZPsG)

It's a `fn(&mut[i32], i32) -> usize`. Uses the same approach as Arnauld's JS answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
#~Roots~x~Count~#2&
```

Takes inputs as equations: `polynomial == 0, x == root`.

If this is not allowed:

### Mathematica, 27 bytes:

```
Count[Roots[#==0,x],x==#2]&
```

[View them on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/22ebb3fe-5609-426e-aa37-3e17c5980f8a)

Comment: `#2~CountRoots~{,#,#}&` inputting `root, polynomial in Null` for 21 on the 2nd

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda p,a:dict(p.roots())[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs43h5cpJzE1KSVQo0Em0SslMLtEo0CvKzy8p1tDUjE6M5eXi5SpQsFWoiDPWNtKqiDPSNdeq0DYBChZl5pVopGkU6BhqagIAA-UUNA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Inputs a polynomial \$p\$ and a root \$a\$ of \$p\$.
Uses `p.roots()` which returns the roots of \$p\$ along with their multiplicity as a list of \$2\$-element tuples. Turning this into a dictionary requires only a simple lookup of the root to find its multiplicity.

Answer (score 2):

## [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), 29 bytes

```
f(p,a):=hipow(factor(p),x-a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc9NCsIwEAXgvafoMslkoEmnKVq8SiEIwSxqQymY28ckKqggXb3F@5if2UY/25QcC9Ly0/nqw3Jnzl62ZWWBy4iWjyms/rYxx@LUgRZx0jiICCQbxfl4@NsifdeEJArqK8pUNu2uULtCf4rSmmoInvLlQOWDfoYNqMrBBkybo0dVk0BTyQ7Vsf4Dht570gM)

Factorises \$p(x)\$, taken as a built-in polynomial object, and returns the exponent of \$x-a\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 103 bytes

```
k=l.length
L=[0...k-1]
I=[n...k-1]
f(l,R)=L[[0^{total(R^{[0...k-n]}I!l[n+1...]/(I-n)!)^2}forn=L]=0].min
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nsdbxpa3hv)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gntg6ssytd)

Function \$f(l,R)\$ takes in a list of coefficients in ascending order and the root \$R\$.

Uses Arnauld's strategy of repeatedly taking derivatives, so go upvote his answer too!

There's probably a way of shortening the `L=[...]` `I=[...]` part since they are so similar but I don't see it at the moment.

Might post an explanation if I feel like it, though if you understand Desmos enough it shouldn't be too hard to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
Ｗ¬↨⮌θη≔ΦＥθ×κλλθＩ⁻ＬＡＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLCsIwFET3fsVd3gsptKUUpCsVBMGKiLvSRSihDca0ebR@fkzEzczhMMwwcTvMXIXwmaQSgLfZ45E7gQ@xCRvbEIOJiODgnBw1nqXywmLLFzQMnvItHL4YKKIUDAw1u7uV2uOJO4@t1KvDq9Cjn/Cil9VjWv6FicfUhNB1OYO6YpAV@5JBWeUJ6yR/FF3RR9@HbFNf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses the same differentiation trick as @Arnauld's answer.

```
Ｗ¬↨⮌θη
```

While the root is a root of the current polynomial (defaulting to the input polynomial) (using base conversion of the reversed polynomial to evaluate it)...

```
≔ΦＥθ×κλλθ
```

... differentiate the polynomial.

```
Ｉ⁻ＬＡＬθ
```

Output the difference in degree of the input and final polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 51 bytes

```
{((|@^p,0),*[^(*-1)].produce(*×$^r+*)...*[*-1])-2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczhCoIwFAXgVzmIxLbc2MYygpTeQzSklAJDsfoh6nP0QD3YmiFB4J/L5Tvn3qZoq9DeOqxKRLYnZDhkTSBpwJKMMK5oKpq2Pj9PBWHvl5@1a0aFECxxWUq5Hu097@CRXlyK/DzSAL145NdqRBSjLzH4x9FDWbcgewUNvoWJAyhX/ANuZuEGG3AN6VAumFow/TUDOamBmlxNT39lpRG6VLmhzbTsHJj52H4A)

This is an anonymous function that takes a polynomial as an array of coefficients in descending order, and a root.  The arguments are stored in the placeholder variables `@^p` and `$^r` respectively.

The outermost parenthesized expression is a list, where each element is a list of polynomial coefficients followed by a remainder.  `(|@p, 0)` is the first element of the list, the input polynomial with a zero remainder appended.  Each successive term is the previous polynomial divided by \$x - r\$.  The iteration ends when the the remainder term, `*[*-1]`, is nonzero/truthy.

`*[^(*-1)]` strips off the final remainder element of the previous coefficient/remainder list, and `.produce(* × $^r + *)` performs polynomial long division by \$x - r\$.

Finally, the `- 2` coerces the entire list of polynomials to a number, its length, and subtracting 2 gives the multiplicity of the root.

Comment: x-r is not a monomial.

Comment: @loopywalt Huh, true enough.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)

```
+/@E.1{::p.
```

Accepts a list of coefficients in ascending order

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxWlvfwVXPsNrKqkAPIrJbkys1OSNfId5QIU3BBKg-3gRIGSrEGykYQlQsWAChAQ)

```
+/@E.1{::p.
     1{::p. NB. monadic fork
         p. NB. computes boxed result of multipler;roots
     1{::   NB. fetches and lists contents of second box
+/@E.       NB. x E. y finds occurrences of x in y, returns boolean list
  @         NB. atop, executes E. dyadically and +/ monadically
+/          NB. sum reduce
```

Comment: 11 bytes: [`+/@E.1{::p.`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxWlvfwVXPsNrKqkAPIrJbkys1OSNfId5QIU3BBKg-3gRIGSrEGykYQlQsWAChAQ)

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: The train has even number of parts `+/@E. 1 {:: p.`, so it is parsed as a hook `+/@E. (1 {:: p.)` meaning `x +/@E. (1 {:: p.) y`.

Comment: Smart. I find myself blind to hooks a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/calculator), 66 bytes

```
f=x
InputBox(f
k
InputBox(k
l=Flatten(Factors(f
l(IndexOf(x-k,l)+1
```

Input the polynomial in the first Input Box, and the root in the second Input Box.

All the heavy lifting is done by the built-in `Factors`.

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://geogebra.org/calculator/qfzq8d9g)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I don't understand the challenge! So a port of Arnauld's solution will have to do for now.

```
T?J:Òß¡T±X*VpY X*YÃÅ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=VD9KOtLfoVSxWCpWcFkgWCpZw8U&input=WzAsNjQsLTE5MiwyNDAsLTE2MCw2MCwtMTIsMV0KMg)

```
T?J:Òß¡T±X*VpY X*YÃÅ     :Implicit input of array U & integer V
T?                       :If T (initially 0) is truthy (not 0) then return
  J                      :  -1
   :                     :Else
    Ò                    :  Negate the bitwise NOT of (i.e., increment)
     ß                   :  Recursive call with argument (The unchanged V is implicit)
      ¡                  :    Map each X at 0-based index Y in U
       T±                :      Increment T by
         X*VpY           :      X multiplied by V raised to the power of Y
               X*Y       :      Return X*Y
                  Ã      :    End Map
                   Å     :    Slice off the first element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes

Naïve solution:

```
(P,r)->valuation(P,x-r)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 116 bytes

Port of [@corvus_192's Rust answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253300/110802) in Scala.

---

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBBa8MgFIDv@RWPnrSzkoTQsgYLPe6w09hp9PCWmNRgbFDbspX89kyTHQd74PMpnx@@5yrUOF0@O1l5eEVl4JEA1LKBPhwI2tbt4Wgtfn28eatMe6J7eDfKgwhkckMNzR7IQrwYf2IQMgVxiHuApgdBZqk43NBCJ9LyflZaEpLC1XilAbmWpvVnyr/VQJDyHodHhU4Sxar5mYZaVOse/ZkPlzuxTFHuL8FeIlF0LVRZj9xdeyFS2j2JrOzGCUKgc9J60iyfIwWDzY5BziCjcYEQkNPkX3JTzGj2J5oy2EY8ew50XqSx3MbLufo15LNguwiGMESvDVkdtQYvnYfYrIMhmmu@itSYjNMP)

```scala
{(a,r)=>var j=0;while((0 until a.length).zip(a).map{case(i,c)=>val d=c*math.pow(r,i).toInt;a(i)*=i;d}.sum==0)j+=1;j}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9NS8QwEIbv/RXvMVmzpS2lsoUKHj14Ek@yh7GfKf0izbqo9LfXJFuhB8FAMpOZZ968mXPqaF3H97bMNZ5JDvj2gKKs0JsLI1XPKR6Vos@3F63kUJ95itdBamSOBD6oQ5WC3aCnQZ8FzMmRPdhoOTASULbiJuyMQms6wXa/NrIrwViAy6BlB/K7cqh1w/0vOTHifk/T9pxdOc2GlgL5TvPXS2F0cxyMf93403hlSkByX4/GzA4lJjkOGeSuVmz54s@XHpnxx43Nuwzh1mhdXDwXaJ5LpVl1@zmLBY73ApFAyO228xH/nzzGDg3/RAOBxOLhydBRHNg0sUWXbQqRE0iswOIt6/oD)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f: (Array[Int], Int) => Int = { (a, r) =>
      var j = 0
      while ((0 until a.length).zip(a).map {
        case (i, c) =>
          val d = c * math.pow(r, i).toInt
          a(i) *= i
          d
      }.sum == 0) j += 1
      j
    }

    assert(f(Array(4, -7, 2, 1), 1) == 2)
    assert(f(Array(4, -7, 2, 1), -4) == 1)
    assert(f(Array(0, 64, -192, 240, -160, 60, -12, 1), 2) == 6)
  }
}
```