# Find The Real Solutions of a Cubic

Tags: code-golf, math

### Description

All cubic equations can be solved, and every cubic has at least one solution. The goal of this challenge is to find the real solutions to a given cubic using inputs, and (obviously) the smallest program size.

### Rules

The solution must find the real solutions of a cubic correctly, using any method. The cubic must be in the standard form
$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$$

The first coefficient cannot be zero, as then it would be a quadratic. There must a different output if it is zero, and outputting nothing at all is acceptable.

### Scoring

The score is based on the size of the program alone.

### Inputs

The four coefficients of the cubic, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

The input may be formatted however you like.

### Outputs

Every real solution to the cubic. There will either be three, or one for every cubic.

### Example

#### With 3 solutions

Input:

```
1
3
0
-1
```

Output:

```
-2.879
-0.653
0.532
```

#### With 1 solution

Input:

```
1
1
1
1
```

Output:

```
-1
```

### Additional Info

While you can use any method, you can find an image with the cubic equation (similar to the quadratic equation, can solve any cubic every time) equation can be found [here](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/cubic.gif).

You can learn more about cubics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Golf! I suggest you use the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) for your questions next time.

Comment: @Seggan Oh, thank you. I didn't see that, but thanks for telling me!

Comment: Hello and welcome to the code golf stack exchange. Nice first question! It would be appreciated if you could include the definition of the cubic formula in the body of the post so we know which one you are referring to. Also, as Seggan mentioned, the sandbox is a great tool for getting feedback on challenges.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! The problem with requiring answers to use a certain method is that it's "unobservable": you can't tell without looking at the code, and making a subjective judgement on what's close enough. You can get closer to requiring using rhe cubic formula by requiring outputting some intermediate values.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Thank you, although I think I might just remove the requirement for the formula, as it railroads everyone into the same solution.

Comment: @cs1349459 That would be a good idea. I don't actually think we have a regular solve-a-cubic challenge yet either, so it wouldn't be a dupe.

Comment: @lyxal Yes, I was going to, but it is such a long formula it would take a long time to format and create it, that it just isn't worth it.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11694/66833). [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154001/66833). [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200139/66833). [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/21438/66833)

Comment: Also it's implicit in your post, but you don't seem to count quadratics as cubics (implicit because quadratics can have zero real solutions).  Maybe you should mention that the first coefficient can never be 0.

Comment: It would be nice to have two or three more tests cases to cover more situations, like one real triple root (perfect cube polynomial) or one real single root

Comment: I suggest adding `[1,0,0,0]` -> `[0,0,0]` to your test cases ("examples"). (All answers work for this so far, but it is a bit of an edge-case.)

Comment: If a cubic has a multiple root, should it be in the output just once or with correct multiplicit or either way? For example x(x-1)^2=x^3-2x^2+x has real roots 0, 1, 1.

Comment: I think it would be an improvement if the question was self-contained.  You link Wikipedia, but other than that there is no definition of the actual equation to be solved! 
 Presumably you mean `ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0`, but you might have meant `ax^3+bx^2+cx = d`, or `dx^3+cx^2+bx+a=0` or many other variations.  Code Golf questions should always explicitly state the problem, and define the math they use.

Comment: For new answerers who want to avoid builtins: there are some interesting equations for one real root https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root

Comment: You should have more test cases for any answers that use depressed cubics, i.e. special case $$t^3 + pt + q = 0$$ when $$p=0$$.

Comment: _The first coefficient cannot be zero, as then it would be a quadratic. There must a different output if it is zero_ That's a strange requirement. It would have been better to restrict the input to have non-zero leading coefficient, or to allow answers to output the real solutions also when the leading coefficient is zero. I removed my upvote (didn't downvote) because of this

Comment: @LuisMendo the requirements "first coefficient cannot be zero..." and "there must be a different output if it is zero" are contradictory.

Comment: @qwr I take "The first coefficient cannot be zero, as then it would be a quadratic" not as a requirement, but as an explanation of what a cubic is. But yes, the phrasing is not the clearest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `P`, 4 bytes

```
hß∆P
```

[Try It Online!](https://vyxapedia.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJow5/iiIZQIiwiIiwiUCIsIlswLDMsLTMsLTFdIl0=)

Good old built-ins. This may not work on some interpreters until the SymPy ACE vulnerabilities are fixed. Input as a list `[a,b,c,d]`.

Edit: Changed output to the input if leading coefficient is 0.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: by the way, [https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/) is the old version of Vyxal (the link you're using is too), but on the same type of interpreter that vyxal.pythonanywhere.com is on (the latest), with syntax highlighting, etc.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```r
function(c,a=polyroot(c))a[!Im(a)]/!!c[4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcoxCoAwDADA3V90SyCiRSehD/ANIrRGC4I2UhXq66uT63ExW2WNvwNfqwRIOLlz6boPIcodZkika8TCm/wnJmcO2Z4ocgEjukH1OzgcK6V4aMfsgaHUVFNDGjG/)

Input is vector of `d`,`c`,`b`,`a`.  Outputs `Inf` if the cubic coefficient (`a`) is zero.

Using `a[!Im(a)]` to select only real solutions is very susceptible to floating-point rounding errors; the TIO header rounds values less than 0.0000000001 to zero to prevent this.  [Including rounding in the code](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jWSfRtiA/p7IoP79EI1lTMzFa0TNXI1EzztIyVl9RMTnaJPZ/mkayhq6hjoGOsY6hpuZ/AA) costs <s>5</s> 3 more bytes.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 111 bytes

```r
function(e,z=1i^(1:3)){for(i in 1:99)z=z-e%*%rbind(z^3,z^2,z,1)/(z-(x=c(z,z))[2:4])/(z-x[3:5]);if(e)z[!Im(z)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCsIwEADAs7@oh8KubNBt9NBIHuAbQnIwNrAHUwgKZcW3R3CO03rxvbxrfslaYSH1LAnYWcRPWRvIIHVgN8@oXs0yHsZ2l/oATZY0TaTEeAQ1sPkMSooYJneO/9uCdZeIVymwoIb97QmK8bvrBTIwWTqRYcT@Aw)

Non-builtin [Durant-Kerner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) strategy copied from [97.100.97.109's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252321/95126) (upvote that!).
Using this approach to find all the roots in parallel works very nicely with [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s vectorized operations.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
1)?G&ZQ&Zj~)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/31DT3l0tKlAtKqtO8///aEMFYwUDBV3DWAA)

#### How it works

```
       % Implicit input
1)     % Get the first element
?      % If non-zero
  G    %   Push input again
  &ZQ  %   Implicit input. Roots of polynomial. Gives a numeric vector
  &Zj  %   Push real and imaginary parts
  ~    %   Negate. Gives "true" if imaginary part is zero, or "false" otherwise
  )    %   Keep only real parts corresponding to "true".
       % Implicit end
       % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>143</s> <s>134</s> 133 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,c,d,R=[-1,1j,1]:[R:=[(z:=R[2])-(((a*z+b)*z+c)*z+d)/(z-R[0])/(z-R[1])]+R for i in" "*99]and[x for x in R[:3]if x.imag==0]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY-xCsIwGIR3nyJ0SuofbezSBvISWUOGtCEasWkpFWp3n8Kli76Tb2OtFRc5OI4PDu5uj-bSHeowjvdz52j2vDpxMlVhDTJQQAkWpFCUATsC01xJLhQeuJBqpwnFGJt4WBdksvJtlmzxQKVK9BKYJnotkatb5JEPEYriPNcmWNXPsJ8gkoqn2jvUb3xl9kIkehmTNa0PHXaYQQoJUEbI6ofoHzaLkE__e-oF)

This is the first solution that doesn't use a builtin, and it suffers greatly for it. Instead, I'm using the [Durant-Kerner method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) to find all approximations, then filtering for whether they're complex.

---

-9 bytes from @Steffan for various small changes.

Comment: Your editor converted the tabs to spaces again, so this is only 137 bytes

Comment: you can save another byte by not using the walrus operator (it's often shorter): [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5NDoIwGET3nKJh1cJXpLIRDJfotumCv2pNBNKUBHsC7-CGjR7A23gbq-hmMslMXt7tMV7sceiX5T5ZRXeva9sppHAFNTTQAi8FZcBOwCQpAqQGgzTSfYjCKM8LV3KxlXt_chRjXEUuromP5hMt2WBHuUjlr3iEjHmATGcn04v5S5s9DXFRZFIrNCf6XB3KMk1Sufo8R6N7ixVmkEEKlBGyDn_hNw)

Comment: and `0.0` can be `0.`, which can be just `0`

Answer (score 4):

Both functions below take a polynomial in `x`.

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 27 bytes

```
p->if(#p>3,polrootsreal(p))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGiNNulpSVpuha7C3TtMtM0lAvsjHUK8nOK8vNLiotSE3M0CjQ1ISpu2hYUZeaVaKRpVMQZaxtrVcQZ6RpqanIhiwLFtCu0UUWNdCtA6iCGLFgAoQE)

Returns `0` for quadratics and below.

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 101 bytes

```
p->k=[Pi,I,2];for(q=1,99,k-=[subst(p,x,k[i])/vecprod([k[i]-z|z<-k[^i]])|i<-[1..3]]);[r|r<-k,!imag(r)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGiNNulpSVpuhY3Uwt07bJtowMydTx1jGKt0_KLNAptDXUsLXWydW2ji0uTiks0CnQqdLKjM2M19ctSkwuK8lM0okFc3aqaKhvd7Oi4zNhYzZpMG91oQz09YyDbOrqopggoo6OYmZuYrlGkGQu1zLagKDOvRCNNoyLOWNtYqyLOSNdQU5MLWRQopl2hjSpqpFsBUgcxZMECCA0A)

Yet another implementation of the Durand–Kerner method.

Comment: I think the all-builtin one (```polrootsrreal```) needs a bit more to prevent it from trying to solve quadratic equations when the coefficient ```a``` is zero (from the challenge: "There must a different output if it is zero")

Comment: @DominicvanEssen OK, is this good?

Comment: Looks good to me now.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8? 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṛ/ȧÆr,N+AƲƇ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of the coefficients (`[d,c,b,a]`) and yields a list of the (one or three) real roots, unless `a` is zero in which case it yields an empty list.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//4bmbL8inw4ZyLE7Ei0HGssaH////Wy0xLDAsMywxXQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hztn6J5YfbivS8TvS7Xhs07H2/4fbj056uHOGZuT//9HRuoY6BjrGOoaxXDrRhjpgCGJa6JjoGEGYBjogCFcA5ICYYH2GIHYsAA).

...\$8\$ bytes if we can handle `a` being zero (in which case it works for all polynomials):

```
Ær,NċAƲƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5GO35Fux2ObjrX///8/WtdQx0DHWMcwFgA)

#### How?

The heavy lifting is done by a built-in...

```
ṛ/ȧÆr,N+AƲƇ - Link: coefficients, P = [d,b,c,a]
 /          - reduce (P) by:
ṛ           -   right
               -> a
   Ær       - polynomial roots (of P)
  ȧ         - logical AND
               -> [d,c,b,a] or 0
          Ƈ - keep those for which (with 0, keep those of range(0)=[]):
         Ʋ  -   last four links as a monad - f(x):
      N     -     negate (x)
     ,      -     (P) paired with (that)
        A   -     absolute value (of x)
       ċ    -     count occurrences (of that in the pair)
                    -> Truthy (1 or 2*) if x is real, falsey (0) if not
                                  * when x=0
```

Comment: @infinitezero: Would it make sense to ask the OP change that requirement to a *guarantee* that answers are allowed to assume a non-zero first coefficient?  Unfortunately there are some answers that spend bytes dealing with that strange requirement, but other answers like this one which don't.  (It's "strange" because it's basically separate, a different mode of operation, forbidding finding any real roots that do exist.  Maybe intended to discourage builtin polynomial solvers?)

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree. I think it'd be more in the spirit of codegolf to focus on the task and not on unnecessary restrictions.

Comment: @infinitezero fixed it up to adhere to the rules, odd as they are :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 99 bytes

```
import numpy
f=lambda a,b,c,d:[float(i)for i in numpy.roots([a,b,c,d])if round(float(i))!=0if a!=0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcq7CsMwDIXhPU/hbhaoxW22Qp4kZFBqTAWxZVxlyNM77o2WMxz4@fKmd0l9rRyzFDVpjXnrwrBQnD0Zwhlv6K9jWITUMgQphg2nNzwVEX3Y8cMm4GCKrMnbr4fD4FqkdlPNhZPaYM/4GkD3Kz06PP4n18jlieoO)

Comment: Is rounding to the the nearest integer really required? It seems like an unnecessary calculation. I can see the second `round` is required, but the first seems unnecessary. I am no expert of python, so my analysis could be incorrect.

Comment: This does not seem to satisfy "There must a different output if [the cubic coefficient] is zero", and instead outputs solutions to quadratic equations if there are any real ones...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen But my code doesn't output anything!

Comment: With coefficients 0,1,1,0 it seems to output -1, which is the solution to x^2+x=0.  [Try it](https://tio.run/##NcrBCsIwDADQu18RbwkUqXgT9iVjh84SDKxJidlhX18FlXd9/Yin6W0Mad08QPfWjxNPW2lrLVDSmh6p3mferAQKsTkIiH7jxc3ihfOvLSQMbrtW/H86T3kZ3UUDGXO6fmSi8QY)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Fixed! Thanks my bad

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 32 bytes

```
[:{:^:([:-.*./@(=+)){:@:>@p.^:{:
```

I am pretty bad at conditionals in J, but after some finagling, this was the best I could come up with. Expects coefficients as `d,c,b,a`

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmtxUyHaqtoqzkoj2kpXT0tP30HDVltTs9rKwcrOoUAvDigHVWeoyZWanJGvkKamZ6dgo2SoEKtgrGCioKIQbwg001jBEMYwAFoEEjeEaFywAEIDAA)

```
[:{:^:([:-.*./@(=+)){:@:>@p.^:{:
                    {:@:>@p.^:{:  : u^:v executes u if v is true, else return x
                              {:  : is last item 0?
                    {:@:>@p.      : if non-zero
                          p.      : converts coefficient form to multiplier-roots form
                        >         : unbox the results
                    {:            : take the roots, not the multiplier
  {:^:([:-.*./@(=+))              : The check for only one real
      ([:-.*./@(=+))              : u(v(x)) where u is -. and v is *./@(=+)
               (=+)               : each x equal to its complex conjugate?
           *./                    : AND reduce result
         -.                       : negate result
  {:                              : if roots are not all reals, take the last value

extra:
u@v -> apply u monadically to v(x) for every application of v
u@:v -> apply u to the entire result of v(x)
[:u v -> strictly u(v(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 20 bytes

```
1(#~]=+)@{::[:p.]*{:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxxVBDuS7WVlvTodrKKtqqQC9Wq9oKInXTQpMrNTkjXyFNTc9OwUbJUCFWwQQIVRTiDYHGGCsYwhgGMKgDljaE6F-wAEIDAA)

Takes `d c b a`, and returns the array of real roots, or an empty array if `a` is 0.

```
1(#~]=+)@{::[:p.]*{:
                ]*{:    multiply the entire polynomial with `a`
                        which doesn't change the roots if `a` is nonzero
                        but gives 0 0 0 0 otherwise, which has zero roots according to `p.`
            [:p.    convert to multipler-roots form
1        {::        extract the roots
 (     )@      filter real roots:
  #~]=+        filter the list by "complex conjugate equals self"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 50 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z89Ojs@Vt86OzraJDZW0dbAyjY4P6csNboiLigxLz012kBHwThWL9vW1kCnQicoNTGnONb6f0BRZl5JdHp0ta6hjoGOsY5hbay@vl8sF7q4AUT8PwA)

```
g[k_]/;k[[4]]!=0:=Solve[x^Range[0,3].k==0,x,Reals]
```

Input is the number of coefficients in reverse order `{d, c, b, a}`. This defines a function `g` only if the `4th` argument is unequal 0. Otherwise this function remains undefined and returns the function call as output. Uses the built-in `Solve` function over the `Reals` domain.

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nR1kBNzS84P6csNbpCWVvZSK3OLT8npU5RWVmnQicoNTGnOFbtf0BRZl6JQ3q0oY6xjoGOrmEsF0zEAEPEEMgH4tj/AA)

Comment: [35](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277XznOwC84P6csNbpCWVvZSK3OLT8npU5RWVmnQicoNTGnOFbtf0BRZl6JQ3q0oY6xjoGOrmEsF0zEAENE1xAoYKBjGPsfAA) returning as many `{Indeterminate}`s as the non-cubic has roots

Comment: @att since this is so majorly different, you might as well post this as your own solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

```
#^0NSolve[x#+#2&~Fold~!##,x,Reals]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7XznOwC84P6csNbpCWVvZSK3OLT8npU5RWVmnQicoNTGnOFbtf2BpZmqJQ0BRZl5JtHKdW1F@rktmemZJcV2Frl2ag4NyrFpdcHJiXl01V7WhjrGOgY6uYa0OV7UBEtsQyAKzuWr/AwA)

Input `[a, b, c, d]`. If \$a=0\$, returns a list of as many `{Indeterminate}`s as there would be solutions.

When given non-equation expressions, `NSolve` [finds their roots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163273).

```
          x#+#2&~Fold~!##           convert to a polynomial in x
   NSolve[               ,x,Reals]  get real solutions
#^0                                 invalidate solutions if a=0
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 29 bytes

```
syms a b c d;roots([a b c d])
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!